# Attempting to format a table in JAVA using PrintF

Tags: java, formatting

I am currently trying to format my output to create a table as seen below. The issue I am running into is that I can't seem to format the columns in a manner that they are all in line with each other as the first column of Strings are different characters.
I can't seem to figure it out so your help is greatly appreciated.

Province Class:

```
public class Provinces {

private String province;
private String rateType;
private double provincialRate;
private double canadaRate;

public Provinces() {

}

public Provinces(String province, String rateType, double provincialRate, double canadaRate) {
    this.province = province;
    this.rateType = rateType;
    this.provincialRate = provincialRate;
    this.canadaRate = canadaRate;

}

public String getProvince() {
    return province;
}

public void setProvince(String province) {
    this.province = province;
}

public String getRateType() {
    return rateType;
}

public void setRateType(String rateType) {
    this.rateType = rateType;
}

public double getProvincialRate() {
    return provincialRate;
}

public void setProvincialRate(double provincialRate) {
    this.provincialRate = provincialRate;
}

public double getCanadaRate() {
    return canadaRate;
}

public void setCanadaRate(double canadaRate) {
    this.canadaRate = canadaRate;
}

public double calculateTotal() {
    double total = 0.0;
    total = provincialRate + canadaRate;
    return total;
}



}
```

Taxes2018 Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Taxes2018 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Provinces> provinces = new ArrayList<Provinces>();

        provinces.add(new Provinces("Alberta","GST",0.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("British Columbia","GST+PST",7.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Manitoba","GST+PST",8.0,5.0));     
        provinces.add(new Provinces("New Brunswick","HST",10.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Newfoundland and Labrador","HST",10.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Northwest Territories","GST",0.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Nova Scotia","HST",10.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Nunavut","GST",0.0,5.0));  
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Ontario","HST",8.0,5.0));          
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Prince Edward Island","HST",10.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Quebec","GST+QST",9.975,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Saskatchewan","GST+PST",6.0,5.0));
        provinces.add(new Provinces("Yukon","GST",0.0,5.0));



    System.out.println("==============================================================================================");           
    System.out.printf("%5s%18s%23s%21s%14s\n%38s\n", "Canada's Province", "Rate Type", "Provincial Rate","Canada Rate", "Total","(HST, GST, PST)");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");           

    for (Provinces Provinces: provinces) {

        System.out.printf("%-15s%18s%15.2f%.2f%.2f\n", Provinces.getProvince(), Provinces.getRateType(), Provinces.getProvincialRate(), Provinces.getCanadaRate(), Provinces.calculateTotal());

    }


}

}
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaF1U.png)

Comment: Please provide the Provinces class.

Comment: Changes have been made!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have been fiddling around with your format, I have decided to make my own format from scratch so here it is

`%-30s%-18s%-23s%-15s%s`

and in code

```
System.out.printf("%-30s%-18s%-23s%-15s%s\n", Provinces.getProvince(), Provinces.getRateType(), Provinces.getProvincialRate(), Provinces.getCanadaRate(), Provinces.calculateTotal());
```

You can control the padding by changing the numbers and fit your needs, so basically all its doing is padding it after each String you might want to use something else rather then String but that gets the job done and you can tweak it to how ever you want after that.